# C++, Python embedding: Importing torch/sklearn library on embedded python code throws a DEBUG: caught signal to interrupt error

Tags: c++, pytorch, python-import, python-embedding

I have written a program in C++ which uses python embeddings in order to call a python module, which utilizes the numpy and pytorch libraries.
When using solely the numpy library I can successfully call and return from the module without any errors.
However, when I add the "import torch" command on my module, my program throws the following error:

> DEBUG: caught signal to interrupt (Child exited).

The problem also occurs when I import torch/sklearn modules using the PyRun_SimpleString() function.

Part of my program where I call the respective imports:

```cpp
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy");
cout << "numpy ok" << endl;
PyRun_SimpleString("import torch");
cout << "torch ok" << endl;
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following output:

```
numpy ok
DEBUG: caught signal to interrupt (Child exited).
```

I compile and link my program using the `python3-config --cflags` and python3-config --ldflags` outputs.
I have also pytorch installed for my python3.6 as can be seen from the code below:

```cpp
PyRun_SimpleString("import importlib");
PyRun_SimpleString("flag = importlib.util.find_spec('torch')");
PyRun_SimpleString("print(flag is not None)");
```

This code prints `True`, showing the torch is actually installed but for some reason can not be loaded. 
Finally, the same behavior occurs when trying to import the sklearn library. Thank you.